# How to print multiple max values (integers) in Python list?

Tags: python, list, max

I have a voting program where I need to find the winner of a vote or find out whether there was a draw between the most-voted for people. I tried to do this by finding the max value in a list (which contains how many votes they got each), and then checking whether any other values equal it.

The list used is called votesEach, which is supposed to correspond to candGroup (so the first value in votesEach is the amount of votes for candidate a).

Here is my issue:
If votesEach equals [1, 0, 0, 0], the right thing is shown (i.e. candidate a has won). However,
if there are multiple winners, only one of them is displayed (or even the wrong one sometimes). For example, if votesEach is [0, 0, 1, 1], the winners should be c and d, but a is shown twice.

What could be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
candGroup = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
votesEach = [0, 0, 1, 1]
winnercounter = 0
for i in votesEach:
    if i == max(votesEach):
        winnercounter += 1
if winnercounter == 1:
    winner = candGroup[votesEach.index(max(votesEach))]
    print(winner, 'has won the vote with', max(votesEach), 'votes')
else:
    print(votesEach)
    for i in votesEach:
        if i == max(votesEach):
            print(candGroup[votesEach[i]], 'has won the vote with', max(votesEach), 'votes')
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The problem is in the last line, because you are getting the index for the first appearance of i. I‘ll try to give an answer.

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ my expected output for votesEach = [0, 0, 1, 1] would be it printing 'c has won the vote with 1 votes [new line] d has won the vote with 1 votes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple method,

```
candGroup = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
votesEach = [0, 0, 1, 1]
# Zip function will zip two iterators and gives res in tuple like ('a',0),('b',0)..
# So by using those data we can filter out the winners by using maximum votes by creating a dictionary in a smart way
winners = {cand:votes for cand,votes in zip(candGroup,votesEach) if votes==max(votesEach)}
# Then here by iterating over each winners and getting the candidate name and votes
for candidate, votes in winners.items():
    print(candidate, 'has won the vote with', votes, 'votes')
```

**Output:**

```
c has won the vote with 1 votes
d has won the vote with 1 votes
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how the last 3 lines work? I've seen something like this a few times but didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

At first find the maximum vote(s):

```
maximum_vote = max(votesEach)
max_positions = [i for i, j in enumerate(votesEach) if j == maximum_vote]
```

Then find the winner(s):

```
winners = [candGroup[i] for i in max_positions]
```

winners would be a list containing the name of the winners.

Comment: @noobprogrammer Simple and obvious. At first finds the position of the maximum votes, then maps them to the corresponding candidates.

Answer (score 0):

```
candGroup = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
votesEach = [0, 0, 1, 1]

winningScore = max(votesEach)
winnersIndex = [index for index, value in enumerate(votesEach) if value == winningScore]

for i in winnersIndex:
    print(candGroup[i], "has won the vote with", winningScore, "votes" )
```